# Is tweenlite faster/lighter than manual animation?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I was wondering is there a difference between the processor usage when using tweenlite or animating the same clip manually? Considering it's vectors and also dynamic text with it.

Similarly, if we animate manually or copy the code snippet produced by that animation. Would that make a difference on the CPU usage?

Comment: by "manually" do you mean using the native Tween function, or do you mean actually repositioning display objects based on a timer or framerate yourself?

Comment: i assume "manually" means good old fashioned keyframe animation made in flash authoring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really know whether the code generated from IDE tweening is faster (I highly doubt that, as there would be an overhead of initializing motion and easing functions and variables) but performance-wise here are some general factors you need to consider:

- Every frame (**not** keyframe) in a classic motion tween is precalculated and stored, adding some little bytes to your SWF. In particularly long animations these add up to kilobytes. This is not the case with shape tweens, where only keyframes are stored.
- Because the motion tweens are precalculated, CPU is free of calculating the transformations, etc. in each frame between keyframes. However this gain really doesn't matter very much as the really intensive CPU demand results from calculating the blending (alpha, layer blending, etc.) and rendering of large areas every frame. That means, if you are moving huge bitmaps or sprites, neither classic nor algorithmic tweening is going to help you much. You should try to minimize the redrawn areas in that situation.
- Shape tweens can be really CPU intensive when used on paths with many control points. Still it is generally lighter than blending and transformation.
- Texts and sophisticated vectors generally benefit greatly from bitmap caching.
- Until recently (ie. prior to Flash CS3, IIRC) you were limited to basic easing in manual tweens, so that was a real show stopper. I still find it clearer to express them as easing functions.

Comment: That is quite comprehensive, but here is the bit. But my question still would be in case of a motion tween (not shape) of say average sized vector. Which would be faster, classic manual tween or tweenlite?

Comment: Theoretically, if you are doing a very simple animation (say, just tweening the x value of a small object along a horizontal line, maybe with some alpha tweening), then both the classic and algorithmic tweening should give you the same result. This is because you wouldn't be tapping the FPS limit the player is able to render.

Of course, there should be an overhead (ie. some milliseconds of extra CPU processing) for the function calls and array and dictionary processing done by TweenLite. This is, however, often negligible even in the extreme cases.

Comment: Also this might be interesting, if you haven't seen it already: http://www.greensock.com/tweening-speed-test/  It only involves various tweening engines though, not classical tweening.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that classic tweening is frame based where TweenLite (and Max, etc.) is based on time. That means that, if you construct by hand a 30 frame animation in a 30 fps movie, the FP will try to render every frame regardless of how much seconds has passed. It *should* drop the frames, but it can't know, in advance, which frames are most intensive; so it loses much of the time in rendering. This is not the case with TweenLite, as it depends on the timers, not frames. It will render a state and in the next possible instant it calculates where it is on the time graph...

Comment: ... and render its list accordingly. You can test this by placing a huge bitmap and applying an 200px BlurFilter on it over 60 frames in a 60 fps movie. In classical tweening, FP will take its time to process the animation every frame and the result spans over 10-15 seconds on my machine. TweenLite however just shows the original frame, and in the next instant the completely blurred bitmap. This is because, in TweenLite's perspective, 1 second has passed and the animation should be complete.